# SQL query skipping over row inside PHP for loop

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

I'm trying to create a time table using PHP and mysql.

Basically I have A for loop that goes from 600 to 2200, and inside that loop another loop that goes from 1 to 7 for each day of the week.

Inside my second for loop, I search my database for an event where `day` is equal to my iteration inside my second loop, and the start and end is within the range of my first for loop. I have two events that should be returned. However it skips over the first one and only returns the second.

Here is my code:

```
        $week = 1;
        for($i = 600; $i <=2200; $i += 25){
            echo $i .'</br>';
            for($j = 1; $j < 8; $j++){
                echo $j .'</br>';
                $query = 'SELECT * FROM `event` WHERE `week` =:week AND `day` =:day AND (`start` <=:start AND `end` >=:start)';
                $stmt = $dbh->prepare($query);
                $stmt->bindParam(':week', $week);
                $stmt->bindParam(':day', $j);
                $stmt->bindParam(':start', $i);
                if($stmt->execute()){
                    if($stmt->rowCount() > 0){
                        $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                        print_r($row);
                    }
                }
            }
```

I also tried

```
SELECT *
FROM `event`
WHERE `week` =:week AND `day` =:day AND (:start  BETWEEN `start` AND `end`)
```

and in both cases I get the same outcome.

Here is what is inside my events table 
[image]

as soon as $i is equal to 900 it should return row of id 9, however it doesnt, but when $i is 1875, it prints out that event.

Here is a picture when I try to put it directly in phpmyadmin

[image]

Can anyone see why this is?

Comment: This seems like a really inefficient way to query a MySQL database.  Why are you using these loops the first place?  Please show us sample input/output, and explain what you are trying to do here.

Comment: When you run the SQL with hard code params when  `:start = 900` is it works?

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen Im trying to create a time table, $i is the time from 6:00 am to 10:00 pm and $j is the day of the week. The output is simply to test right now it echos the time $i then echos $j for each day. At $i = 900 I expect to print_r my row but it doesnt, then at $i = 1875 it prints event id = 4.

Comment: @ David Winder yes, I will add a picture in my post to show.

Comment: I don't see the $day and $start variables set in advance, like the $week is set, maybe this is the problem ? and I agree with @Tim Biegeleisen, the issue can be better treated, with a single MySQL query, for example

Comment: @GuyL start and day are $i and $j respectively

Comment: But their first allocation happens only **after** the 1st query iteration is being executed

Comment: @GuyL Im not sure what you mean, $i and $j are defined before the query , :start and :day binds them to the appropriate variables.

Comment: read your code, you bind $i and $j  **after**  the SQL query is executed, that means that in the 1st iteration, they are not bound

Answer (score 0):

Problem was the 'start' and 'end' datatype, just realized they were varchar and not int.